# Unable to cast object of type EntityCollection<Derived> to EntityCollection<Base>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, casting, polymorphism

I'm using reflection to get `EntityCollection<Derived>` properties from my EF4 domain entities. An example entity may have many collections that hold types which have a common base. `GetValue()` returns an `object` but I need to convert it to an `EntityCollection<Base>` or even just `IEnumerable<Base>`. But how? (oops, casting to IEnumerable does work as of C#4)

**Example Model**

```
public class Derived : Base { ... }
public class AnotherDerived : Base { ... }
public class Example : Base
{
    public virtual ICollection<Derived> Items { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AnotherDerived> OtherItems { get; set; }
}
```

I have a hard time understanding casting and polymorphism. I think I was able to do this successfully with reflected `DbSet<Derived>` casting them to `IQueryable<Base>`. But with `EntityCollection` I cannot get the reflected object back into a usable form.

**Methods**

```
public static List<T> GetCollectedEntities<T>(this BaseEntity entity)
    where T : BaseEntity
{
    var result = new List<T>();
    foreach (var c in GetCollections<T>(entity))
        foreach (var item in (EntityCollection<T>)c) //ERROR
            result.Add(item);
    return result;
}

public static List<object> GetCollections<T>(this BaseEntity entity)
    where T : BaseEntity
{
    var collections = new List<object>();
    var props = from p in entity.GetType().GetProperties()
                let t = p.PropertyType
                where t.IsGenericType
                && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>)
                let a = t.GetGenericArguments().Single()
                where a == typeof(T) || a.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T))
                select p;
    foreach (var p in props)
        collections.Add(p.GetValue(entity, null));
    return collections;
}
```

**Real World Error**

```
Unable to cast object of type  
'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1[HTS.Data.ServiceOrder]'  
to type  
'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1[HTS.Data.IncomingServiceOrderBase]'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the sort of thing you should be able to do, doesn't it? But it's not allowed, and here's why.

`EntityCollection<T>` is writable, so if you cast a `EntityCollection<Derived>` to an `EntityCollection<Base>`, you can then insert Base objects into the collection. That means you now have instances of a class that isn't Derived and isn't a child of Derived in an `EntityCollection<Derived>`. What then? An iterator over `EntityCollection<Derived>` that expects a Derived is going to fail in all sorts of exciting ways.

Comment: What about casting to `IEnumerable<Base>` then?

Comment: LOL I thought I had already tried it and got an error. It works. Thank you.

Comment: If you're in C# 4, you can make covariant assignments of IEnumerable<T>. It won't work in earlier versions of .net though. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx